# How to override a npm install version check failure?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there a way to override npm's version checking against a packages.json file from command line (`npm install command`)?

I would like to try and install/run a package even though it doesn't match my node.js version.

This is the error I am getting:

```
npm ERR! Unsupported
npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: canvas@0.6.0
npm ERR! Required: {"node":"0.4.x"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.8","node":"v0.5.0-pre"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is go to github package and update the `package.json`. Then just install it locally. But most of the times these version numbers are there for a reason. The node.js api changes sometimes(I believe 0.5.0-pre changed, because socket.io also fails with 0.5.0-pre).

If you for example install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), [nave](https://github.com/isaacs/nave) you can keep several version of node.js side-by-side easily.

Comment: thanks for the nvm/nave tip. wish those node version issues would be stabilized soon.

Comment: @Ben it has stabilized a lot more if you ask me. You bumped the version from 4.x.y to 5.Y.Z. Then you could expect breakage, if you ask me. The stable is still 4.Y.Z so you should still use that for production(5.Y.Z. for toying around). See http://semver.org/ for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails you could still manually download and copy the files in your node_modules folder